# Appending non-React DOM node in React component?

Tags: javascript, dom, reactjs

Google Map nodes do not deal well with being removed from the DOM and everything following is trying to deal with that.

Up until now I've created a map node within a React component at the highest level in my app and never unmounted it. I'm using a bunch of convoluted css to show/hide/position this node based on what route I'm on and also using a lot of logic in the `compenentWillReceiveUpdate()` lifecycle method. I *really* want to use a Google Map within normal mounted/unmounted components and have it nested in the DOM tree where I intend it to be.

I'm playing with placing a `<div id='my-google-map>` node on `<body>` and pulling it into a component in `componentDidMount()` and placing it back on `<body>` when unmounting. Here's what I'm currently working with.

```
componentDidMount: function () {
  const { mapWrapper } = this.refs
  let mapNode = document.getElementById('my-google-map')

  if (!mapNode) {
    mapNode = document.createElement('div')
    mapNode.setAttribute('id', 'my-google-map')
  }

  mapWrapper.appendChild(mapNode)

  this.setState({
    mapNode: mapNode
  })
},

componentWillUnmount: function () {
  document.body.appendChild(this.state.mapNode)
},

render: function () {
  return (
    <div ref='mapWrapper'>
      <span>{this.props.currentDropdown}</span>
    </div>
  )
}
```

This *seems* to be fine and re-renders look like they just ignore the appended node but this feels weird and I'm worried I'm missing something.

Will/when will a future render delete the appended node? Should I just return `false` from `shouldComponentUpdate()` to prevent that?
Is there a better way to have a persistent non-React node within React?

Comment: Have you tried using `react-google-maps` ? It works very well for pretty advanced use-cases. If it doesn't fit your need, maybe you can share more about your use-case ?

Comment: @VonD, How are you handling the Google Map node when the component unmounts? I'm not seeing anything here https://github.com/tomchentw/react-google-maps/blob/master/src/GoogleMap.js but maybe I'm in the wrong file.

Comment: You are right that when the component is unmounted, the DOM node is deleted and that this may lead to memory leaks, which I wasn't aware of. The issue is tracked here: https://github.com/tomchentw/react-google-maps/issues/11. This being said, I've used it in an app where maps with a lot of markers and listeners got mounted/unmounted every time the route changed without any issue. Do you need to keep the map around ? If you don't, and just do this to address the memory leak issue, I think the best thing to do is to clear any listeners/set the map to `null`/etc. on `componentWillUnmount`.

Comment: @VonD, I don't need to keep the DOM node around for any other reason but the fear of memory leaks. :)  I'll try removing listeners and setting map to `null` and see how things go.